# Linking Database Tables Standard Practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am looking for the standard way to handle the following Database Situation.

Two Database Tables - One called `Part`, one called `Return`. In `Part` we have information about Part Number, Cost, Received Date, etc.

`Return` is for if that part is being returned to the vendor.  It will have Return Tracking Number, Shipped Date, and If Credited.

A Part can only have one `Return` but may have none if `Part` is not returned to vendor.

The 3 options I see are:

1. Put both `Part` and `Return` in the same Table but I do not like this idea, table will get too large.
2. Create a field in the 'Part' Table to reference the Id of the `Return` record that it is related to.  My Concern here is there could possibly be free floating `Return` records not attached to a `Part`
3. Create a field in the `Return` Table to reference the Id of the `Part` record it is related to, making the `PartId` field unique so I cannot duplicate `Part` Id.

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using #2 or #3 (or I guess #1 if that is a viable option)?

## UPDATE:

I should have mentioned in reality these tables will be much bigger, and in the application I will be viewing Returns and Parts information in seperate views.

Comment: #2 will create a null field in the part table until it's returned.  #3 only has the record created when it's returned (no null field in the part table).  Make sense as to why #3 is preferable over #2?

Comment: I like #1 because it's seems to be the simplest solution for this problem (by now)

Comment: @Leo - please review update, would you still choose #1.  Thank you.

Comment: @DarylBehrens ha! the little things are usually the most important ones :-)

Comment: @DarylBehrens but I keep my opinion. Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: @Leo: Notice that there are (at least) 3 extra columns required in the parts table, I can't see why having this stored in a separate table is something evil.

Comment: @Gervs actually, except if you have some real performance issue about this, you won't notice a significant difference between #1 and #2. Cratylus' answer seems reasonable to me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution 3:
with the exception that you do not need a unique constraint on part_id, just make it the PK (which is almost the same)

Comment: If I read you right, you are suggesting shared primary key between Part and Return.  If so, I can skip putting in an answer of my own.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have 2 entities, Part and Number with 1-1 relationship where one entity is optional.
In this case you should create a table for each entity (i.e. 2 tables) and use the PK of Part as a reference in the Return table. That is the standard way to represent relationships of this kind.

Comment: Per other comment by Gervs would it be better the make the Part PK a unique reference field in the Return table, or make the Part PK the PK of the returns table?

Comment: A primary key is an unique constraint with a not null constraint, the latter is the only difference (i.e you can set a unique constraint on nullable columns)

Comment: @Gervs:I have no idea how is this related to my answer.As far as I understand the question there would be a record in table Return only if a part is returned.That record would have a reference to a part record in the table Part via a FK constraint (or even without defining a FK if speed is important)